How to export 3D object with shading normal (SN), ambient occlusion (ao), and thickness attributes baked/packed in ply file from blender
I converted the cross.buf file from lusion.co website to cross.ply file and I opened that cross.ply in blender and after seeing these attributes in blender object data properties in attributes section:

daoP_0
daoP_1
daoP_2
daoN_0
daoN_1
daoN_2
SN_0
SN_1
SN_2
ao_0
thickness_0
these are by default:
position
sharp_edge

exported it again as cross.ply and converted that new_cross.ply file to new_cross.buf file and loaded it in the same lusion.co source code and it was working completely fine.
So, I am stuck here at that point, I want to generate/create my own 3D model and export it as .ply file with same attributes and then I will convert it in .buf file and it will be working fine inside the lusion.co source code.
for more info about these custom attributes:
position (P), normal (N), shading normal (SN), ambient occlusion (ao), or thickness.
where _0, _1, _2 represents x, y, z cordinates/values.
